# WordPress and PDO compatibility

Tags: wordpress

I was developing my website with MYSQL, PHP and PDO then a few days ago I learned that i can use WordPress to do it faster and easier. I have also learned that WordPress doesn't use PDO so now I'm stuck trying to figure out what to do with my PDO code to make it work with WordPress. Does anyone have a solution? Or do i have to rewrite my PDO code  in a format supported by WordPress.

Comment: Even if Wordpress doesn't use PDO that doesn't mean that you couldn't use it.

Comment: If you want (need) PDO support, you can use the WP DB Driver plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-db-driver/. WordPress now defaults to mysqli though, if you're using PHP 5.5 (http://make.wordpress.org/core/2014/04/07/mysql-in-wordpress-3-9/) and so it's wise to ALWAYS use the WordPress $wpdb classes for your database access.

Comment: wpdb eats up a ton of memory, and large queries are nearly impossible. it's not wise to always use wpdb

Answer (score 2):

Making a plugin not reliable on WP build in functionality makes it more compatible with other CMS systems out there. I see this as good thing, not bad. If you see a good reason behind this, then by all means go for it. But... perhaps it would be more wise to learn how to do it the WP way. It all depends on what you're trying to achieve.

Here is a quick example on how you can initialize the PDO in WP:

```
$host = 'mysql:host='.DB_HOST.';dbname='.DB_NAME.';charset='.DB_CHARSET;
$pdo = new PDO($host, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
```

Comment: You are forgetting the DB port here, which is within DB_HOST. Something like this.

    $parts = explode(':',$dbname);
    $dbase = $parts[0];
    $port = isset($parts[1])?$parts[1]:3306;

Answer (score 0):

Develop all of your custom code in a plugin. I have a plugin skeleton I uses that introduces OOP and one of the first things I did was include a PDO class.

You access the DB info from wp-config.php via the WP constants DB_HOST, DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD to create your PDO connection.

Comment: Doing two different DB connections is both waste of resources and bound to break something at some point. If you decided that wordpress is a good match for your needs you should accept its problematic parts as well as its good part instead of trying to force it to become something it is not. It will just make you waste more development time in the long run

Comment: I disagree, I can see some heavy things done with the PDO, and you should not use slower code if you are doing custom development.

Comment: Even if you PDO code is faster (and I assume it is unlikely, the main time waster is the actual request) the wordpress code can be made much faster by using caching, something that will not apply to your code since you bypass the wordpress db drivers. Wordpress debugging tools will also not work for you. Obviously not a show stopper if what you need can be done only in PDO, but it is going to cost you additional development time to develop thing that already exist in the wordpress DB driver.

Comment: wpdb seems completely unnecessary when you have PDO. But not only that, wpdb reeks of legacy code because their "prepared" statements are not actually prepared. I recommend ditching wpdb altogether and use native PDO.

Comment: @MarkKaplun Opening another DB connection is not a strain on resources. Other languages hold open connection pools of 10 or more connections. Caching is really not a good enough excuse because anyone that knows to use PDO is probably looking for live data. Furthermore, PDO is not going to provide any less debugging information than the wpdb object, especially when we're talking about custom tables. All of that combined with wpdb's questionable security choices makes PDO a very attractive option to the canny developer.

Comment: @Zei my specific word was "waste" no "strain". anyway, in your php application you welcome to do whatever you want, in wordpress the idea of using PDO is a total no-no. When you develop for a platfor you use the tools of the platform

Answer (score 0):

You can absolutely use PHP's PDO to connect to your WordPress database.

This is the connection code I use in my WordPress plugin. It's been running in production for several months for thousands of free/paid customers on a wide range of hosting.

I originally started with the 2 line answer in this question but added a bit more to it to support IPv6 and socket connections.

```
global $wpdb;

// Parse the DB_HOST using WordPress's specific style
// Supports IPv4, IPv6, and socket connections
$host_data = $wpdb->parse_db_host(DB_HOST);
    
if (is_array($host_data)) {
    list($host, $port, $socket, $is_ipv6) = $host_data;
} else {
    // Redacted. Throw an error or something 
}

// Wrap the IPv6 host in braces as required
if ($is_ipv6 && extension_loaded('mysqlnd')) {
    $host = "[$host]";
}

// Generate either a socket connection string or TCP connection string
if (isset($socket)) {
    $connection_str = 'mysql:unix_socket=' . $socket . ';dbname=' . DB_NAME . ';charset=' . DB_CHARSET;
} else {
    $connection_str = 'mysql:host=' . $host . ';dbname=' . DB_NAME . ';charset=' . DB_CHARSET;

    if (isset($port)) {
        $connection_str .= ';port=' . $port;
    }
}

// Open the connection
$pdo = new PDO($connection_str, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

// Do something with the connection
$rows = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM some_table')->fetchAll();

// Close the connection
$pdo = null;
```

If you're having trouble with any of the specifics, check out the breakdown [here](https://mead.io/2023/02/08/using-php-pdo-with-wordpress/).